# GraphQL: How do you pass args to to sub objects

Tags: graphql

I am using GraphQL to query an object that will be composed from about 15 different REST calls. This is my root query in which I pass in in the ID from the query. This works fine for the main student object that resolves correctly. However, I need to figure out how to pass the ID down to the address resolver. I tried adding args to the address object but I get an error that indicates that the args are not passed down from the Student object. So my question is: How do I pass arguments from the client query to sub objects in a GraphQL server?

```
let rootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    description: `The root query`,
    fields: () => ({
        Student : {
            type: Student ,
            args: {
                id: {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
                }
            },
            resolve: (obj, args, ast) => {
                return Resolver(args.id).Student();
            }
        }
    })
});

export default rootQuery;
```

This is my primary student object that I link the other objects. In this case I have attached the ADDRESS object.

```
import {
GraphQLInt,
GraphQLObjectType,
GraphQLString,
GraphQLNonNull,
GraphQLList
} from 'graphql';

import Resolver from '../../resolver.js'
import iAddressType from './address.js'

let Student = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'STUDENT',
    fields: () => ({
        SCHOOLCODE: { type: GraphQLString },
        LASTNAME: { type: GraphQLString },
        ACCOUNTID: { type: GraphQLInt },
        ALIENIDNUMBER: { type: GraphQLInt },
        MIDDLEINITIAL: { type: GraphQLString },
        DATELASTCHANGED: { type: GraphQLString },
        ENROLLDATE: { type: GraphQLString },
        FIRSTNAME: { type: GraphQLString },
        DRIVERSLICENSESTATE: { type: GraphQLString },
        ENROLLMENTSOURCE: { type: GraphQLString },
        ADDRESSES: {
            type: new GraphQLList(Address),
            resolve(obj, args, ast){
                return Resolver(args.id).Address();
        }}
    })
});
```

Here is my address object that is resolved by a second REST call:

```
let Address = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'ADDRESS',
    fields: () => ({
        ACTIVE: { type: GraphQLString },
        ADDRESS1: { type: GraphQLString },
        ADDRESS2: { type: GraphQLString },
        ADDRESS3: { type: GraphQLString },
        CAMPAIGN: { type: GraphQLString },
        CITY: { type: GraphQLString },
        STATE: { type: GraphQLString },
        STATUS: { type: GraphQLString },
        TIMECREATED: { type: GraphQLString },
        TYPE: { type: GraphQLString },
        ZIP: { type: GraphQLString },
    })

});

export default Address;
```

These are my resolver

```
var Resolver = (id) => {

    var options = {
        hostname: "myhostname",
        port: 4000
    };


    var GetPromise = (options, id, path) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            http.get(options, (response) => {
                var completeResponse = '';
                response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    completeResponse += chunk;
                });
                response.on('end', () => {
                    parser.parseString(completeResponse, (err, result) => {
                        let pathElements = path.split('.');                       
                        resolve(result[pathElements[0]][pathElements[1]]);
                    });
                });
            }).on('error', (e) => { });
        });
    };

    let Student= () => {
        options.path = '/Student/' + id;
        return GetPromise(options, id, 'GetStudentResult.StudentINFO');
    }

    let Address= () => {
         options.path = '/Address/' + id + '/All';
        return GetPromise(options, id, 'getAddressResult.ADDRESS');
    };


    return {
        Student,
        Address
    };
}

export default Resolver;
```

Comment: FallFast: did you find any solution

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ADDRESSES: {
    type: new GraphQLList(Address),
    resolve(obj, args, ast){
        return Resolver(args.id).Address();
    }
}
```

args passed to ADDRESSES are arguments passed to ADDRESSES field at query time. In the resolve method, `obj` should be the student object and if you have an `id` property on it, all you need to do is: `return Resolver(obj.id).Address();`.